# synthesis of bicyclic diol from cyclohexanone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I am trying to come up with a synthetic route for the following reaction, my ideas below it. 
[image]
I think it is a bit of a long shot making this alkene as it would probably be quite strained-any other ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinacol_coupling_reaction would work here

Comment: In cases like this, you can almost always exploit the symmetry of the product.